# How can I create white corners for my grey border in CSS?

Tags: css, web

I have a div and I want it's border to have white corners alongside with the grey border (as on the picture).

[image: Div screenshot]

I tried creating it as a mask like this:

```css
img {
  --s: 50px; /* the size on the corner */
  --t: 5px;  /* the thickness of the border */
  --g: 20px; /* the gap between the border and image */
  
  padding        : calc(var(--g) + var(--t));
  outline        : var(--t) solid #B38184; /* the color here */
  outline-offset : calc(-1*var(--t));
  transition     : .4s;
  mask: 
    conic-gradient(at var(--s) var(--s),#0000 75%,#000 0)
    0 0/calc(100% - var(--s)) calc(100% - var(--s)),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box;
}
```

but then it overlaps the border.
I also tried creating pseudo elements, but didn't succeed as well...

Comment: If you create a SVG of the border, you could use `border-image`. See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/